# How to inject java script in ios 5

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am working on UIWebView in which i am injecting java script like:

```
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"java script"];
```

this was working fine in ios 4.3. but when it not working on ios 5?
how to inject java script on ios 5;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this has not changed in iOS 5. It is a little more finicky with naming, perhaps you need to specify self.webview to make sure you are calling it correctly.